# New app not coming to foreground

Tags: gnome

Loaded 23.04 on a brand new, never had any OS on it, PC (Minisforum UM690).  As far as the PC itself, no problems, but something isn't quite right - when I click an app link on one app that should start up a different app, like a link in an email that should start FireFox, the app does start up, but doesn't come to the foreground, it doesn't even un-minimize.  FireFox is not the only program that exhibits this behavior.

Is there a setting for that somewhere?